# Multiple variables declaration in ejs

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs, embedded-javascript

I am trying to declare and assign a default value to multiple variables. But the value is only getting assigned to last variable

```
<% var scale_text,scale_image = 'free_transform'; %>
```

This print empty:

```
<%- scale_text %>
```

This prints `free_transform`

```
<%- scale_image %>
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Separate the variables with `=` to set them to the same default value.

```
<% var scale_text, scale_image; %>
<% scale_text = scale_image = 'free_transform'; %>
```

Comment: Why is it better?

Comment: @LuisAntonioCanettoliOrdoñez It's better because it won't declare scale_image as a global in quirks mode and won't result in a `ReferenceError` in strict mode. (However, I'm not sure how all that works in EJS.)

Answer (score 4):

What your writing will declare scale_text as an empty variable.

To work the way you want it to you need to do the following

`<% var scale_text = scale_image = 'free_transform'; %>`

However this is probably preferable

`<% var scale_text, scale_image; %>
 <% scale_text = scale_image = 'free_transform'; %>`